# Find the min of $f(x,y) = \frac{1}{2}(x^n+y^n)$ where $x,y\ge 0$ and $x+y=s>0$.

Tags: analysis, functions

I have this function: $f(x,y) = \frac{1}{2}(x^n+y^n)$ and I know that $x,y\ge 0$ and $x + y = s$ where $s\gt0$

I tried to take $y = s-x$ and find minimum of $f(x) = \frac{1}{2}(x^n + (s-x)^n)$ but this didn't work

Any hints on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Is $n$ a positive integer? So what did go wrong? Show your attempt!

Comment: are you familiar with partial derivatives? Treat it as $1$ variable case but both partials need to be zero.

Comment: The Power mean inequality applies directly, and yields
$f(x,y)\geqslant (s/2)^n$.

Comment: @Hanno it depends if $n\in(0,1)$ or not.

Comment: Yes, true Youem , the argument does not apply to the case $n<1$.
Weronia_xoxo should specify the nature of the parameter $n$ ... as already asked by @RobertZ